# ambiguous error when joining same column twice from the same table

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have the following query, I need to line the account_manager column = to prod_id to distribute the account manager name and do the same for the client_id = prod_id to get the producer_name. I created aliases for the producer table but continue to get the column ambiguously defined error.

```
Select rg.group_number, rg.group_name, qo.quote_id, qo.effective_date, qo.quote_type, qo.hra_ind, rg.account_manager, a.name as account_manager_name, rg.client_id, name as producer_name
From qo_quote qo, 
     re_group rg
     
    JOIN producer a ON a.prod_id = rg.account_manager
    JOIN producer b ON b.prod_id = rg.client_id,

        ( select distinct a.group_number, c.prospect_nbr
          from re_current_benefits a, 
               qo_quote b,
               qo_account c
          where a.quote_id = b.quote_id and b.hra_ind = 'Y' and
                a.group_number = c.group_number and c.hcr_ind = '3'
        ) q1

Where q1.prospect_nbr = qo.prospect_nbr and 
      q1.group_number = rg.group_number and qo.effective_date = rg.renewal_date and
      qo.quote_type = 'B' and qo.quote_expiration_ind is null and qo.hra_ind is null and
      qo.mhs_lob_code not in ('DTL1', 'DTL2', 'VIS1')
```

Comment: Please could you re-write your SQL to use ANSI SQL joins rather than Oracle join syntax. The old Oracle syntax is not considered good practice and makes it difficult to distinguish between JOIN logic and filter (WHERE clause) logic

Comment: missing using alias in `name`, in `name as producer_name`

Answer (score 0):

When you joining tables with same columns you must address from which table each ambiguous column, currently you are missing `name`

```
b.name as producer_name
```